# How to select distinct limit the number of records for distinct column?

Tags: mysql, database

Suppose I have the table like in the picture, how can I distinct and limit the number of rows of field `cat3name_EN` ? I would like to have at most two rows of that column.

This is the query I tried

`SELECT DISTINCT cat3, cat3name_EN, title from allplaces a JOIN subcategory b ON a.cat3 = b.cat3`

The current query gives me the result like on the picture but what i want is for each `cat3name_EN` i would like to select at most 2 records not all of the records.

Note that values of `cat3name` are many

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? you seem to mention the correct clauses

Comment: can you please give example of what you are trying to get.. is that only that column, or for example other columns too?

Comment: I have edited my question. I would like to select at most 2 rows with 'cat3' as the distinct column for all existing rows

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs and a desired result